# Pass Git location as a parameter to Maven

Tags: git, maven, jenkins

I have a Jenkins script with this call:

```
mvn "-e -X release:prepare"
```

This fails because git is not found: `/bin/sh: git: command not found`(it is calling git internally).

In the script, I am calling git like this: `sh("{env.git} status")`, which works.

Because of that, I am trying to pass the git environment variable to Maven:

```
mvn "-Dgit=${env.git} -e -X release:prepare"
```

However, this again fails with `/bin/sh: git: command not found`.

So it looks like the address of Git hasn't been properly sent to Maven. Any idea why?

Comment: Have you tried `mvn -Darguments="-Dgit=${env.git}" release:prepare`..?

Comment: Yes, I tried and the result is the same.